# What does “Hashtag blessed” exactly mean here?

Tags: idioms

In the movie “Alexander and his worst day”, Alexander’s elder brother says:

> “I'm dating the hottest girl in school. I'm getting crowned at prom,
>   and once I get my license tomorrow. I kind of have everything I've
>   ever wanted. Hashtag blessed, you know.”

What does “hashtag blessed” mean here? I conjecture it has the same meaning with “God blessed”, but why use “hashtag”? Does it mean: I was labelled by a hashtag which was written by God “I bless you” ?

Comment: He's saying that if he were to "tweet" about his life on Twitter, it would be under the index word "blessed".  Google "Twitter hashtags"

Comment: That's a perfect answer,  I  get it now!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I should add that "hashtag {X}" is a form of (teen) slang, like "23 skidoo" from yesteryear.

Comment: hashtag good question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

'hashtag' has become part of modern speech thanks to [twitter](https://twitter.com) - it's a label preceded by a # (or *hash*) that's used as a way to categorise a tweet’s topic(s), which then makes it easier for people to search for other tweets about those topics. (It has since been used in other social media outlets).

for example, *#StackOverflow* hashtag the returns all tweets [tagged with this hashtag](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23StackOverflow).

Although it's a social media tag, due to its popular usage in social media, it has followed that unfortunate trend of becoming a part of spoken English, particularly in 'teen-speak', similar to when people used to actually say 'LOL' when speaking due to its usage in online forums.

An example of *hashtag* would be:

> "I nearly got into a car crash! Hashtag YOLO."

The speaker is 'tagging' his or her sentence with 'You Only Live Once'

In your example:

> I kind of have everything I've ever wanted. **Hashtag blessed**, you know.”

...the speaker is 'tagging' his previous sentence with **#blessed** - in other words, he's saying that he is [blessed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blessed), or experiencing good fortune in life.

Comment: Wonderful and professional answer,  now I totally understand it,  thank you so much!

Comment: It could also be the result of voice-to-text technology

Comment: Great answer, even if it makes me really really sad.

Comment: _"similar to when people used to actually say 'LOL'"_ Used to? I do it all the time ^_^

Comment: Complete tangent, but is "hashtag yolo" common? Usually I hear/use "yolo" on its own; it's already got enough stylistic/annoyance weight.

Comment: [SNL skit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57dzaMaouXA) exaggerating this

Answer (score 5):

A hashtag is a label used on social media to make it easier for people to find messages with a similar theme. So "hashtag blessed" would look like #blessed on social media, and that is what users could look for. Obviously the character in the film was social-media savvy!

Comment: This is a good explanation of "hashtag", but "blessed" might need some explaining also.

Comment: Thank you,  you are right,  the character in the film was enthusiastic about social media, so what you said could exactly explain what the character wanted to express,  thank you again!